# Draw string with an AffineTransform in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, cgaffinetransform, affinetransform

I am doing some drawing in Swift 3.0 in OS X.

The transform the drawing I am using an AffineTransform from the Foundation API and the NSBezierPath.transform command.

I am trying to draw strings now at the transformed coordinates.

What I would really like is a function to draw a string using:

```
public extension NSString {

    internal func draw( at: CGPoint, withAttributes attrs: [String : AnyObject], withTransform transform: AffineTransform) {

        // What do do here??
        draw( at: CGPoint(x: at.x, y: -at.y), withAttributes: attrs)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to go from an AffineTransform to a CGAffineTransform?

Is there a way to transform a CGPoint to a new point without first putting it in a BezierPath and then using the transform fucntion?